# Is 'please tell me how can I help you' grammatically correct?

Tags: formality

Is it the right way to ask if someone is asking for your help?

Comment: It is grammatically correct, reasonably idiomatic, and polite.

Comment: I'd hate to hurt anyone's feelings but I have to say that it must be found rather reasonably idiotic…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you please tell me what is the food choice/what the food choice is? (inversion)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276133/what-is-the-food-choice-what-the-food-choice-is-inversion) This traditionally has to be seen as a fragment and a direct question: zero punctuation is non-standard. "Please tell me ...  how can I help you?" works.

Comment: Oops, I misread it slightly.  "Please tell me how I can help you" would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks I would normally agree, but I have also seen "tell me how can I help you?" Whatever.

Answer (score -1):

It works but would typically considered a solecism.

But no, the correct sentence is:

> Please tell me how I can help you.

because *"how"* is a clause *(embedded question)*, and therefore it doesn't need inversion as the clause is an affirmative sentence.

Comment: I'd say that it's _how I can help you_ that is a clause, an interrogative one (embedded question) functioning as complement of "tell".